# Does wordpress updation affect wp-content plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

Does wordpress updation affect wp-content plugin folder..Can i upgrade my wp version by   keeping all plugins activated?? I use hotlink protection and when i try to deactivate it its   showing cant open file, how do i do??shall i keep as it is and start upgradation??

Please help me this.Thanks.

[Please only indent text if you want it to appear in a code block]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on how you update / upgrade your WP.

- If you do it manually by FTP :

  Overwrite all files **except** :

  ```
     wp-content ( folder in root dir )
     wp-config.php ( in root) 
     .htaccess
  ```
- If you do it automatically with the wp interface  :

  Same as above , and nothing should be affected . but make sure you
  update ONLY the wp core files, and not the plugins that you do not
  want to update ( the interface will give you ALL updates )

In both ways your plugin files / settings will should not be affected unless they become non-compatible for some reason with the new wp version ( you did not specify )